# Haw to setting phpunit for cod coverage?

Tags: php, phpunit, lumen

My phpunit.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/9.5/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         cacheResultFile=".phpunit.cache/test-results"
         executionOrder="depends,defects"
         forceCoversAnnotation="true"
         beStrictAboutCoversAnnotation="true"
         beStrictAboutOutputDuringTests="true"
         beStrictAboutTodoAnnotatedTests="true"
         failOnRisky="true"
         failOnWarning="true"
         verbose="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="default">
            <directory>tests\driver</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <coverage cacheDirectory=".phpunit.cache/code-coverage"
              processUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
        </include>
    </coverage>

    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="./log/report" lowUpperBound="35"
             highLowerBound="70"/>
        <log type="coverage-clover" target="./log/coverage.xml"/>
        <log type="coverage-php" target="./log/coverage.serialized"/>
        <log type="coverage-text" target="php://stdout" showUncoveredFiles="false"/>
        <log type="testdox-html" target="./log/testdox.html"/>
    </logging>

</phpunit>
```

But I always get wrong:

Warning:       Incorrect filter configuration, code coverage will not be processed

Warning - The configuration file did not pass validation!
The following problems have been detected:

Line 20:

- Element 'filter': This element is not expected.

Test results may not be as expected.

Comment: Are you sure you copy pasted your `phpunit.xml` correctly ? There is no `filter` element there...

Comment: yes, i'am sure.